# Suggested tag-badge is partially updated when criteria are met

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-badges

As mentioned in the recent [blog post about the new profile page](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/):

> And the page adapts to serve our most generous users. Once you’ve earned all the privileges, the “next privilege” bar automatically starts tracking your progress toward your closest tag badge (or another one of your choosing).

I was suggested to answer another question in [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and after I did I got a congratulatory message saying that I'm done. However after I click the **Track the next one >** button I still get the previous badge with stale data (answer count isn't up to date).

[image: screen shot of problem]

BTW, at the time of this question the badge hasn't been awarded and the scenario repeats. Whenever I go to the profile page I get the *Congratulations* message even if I've previously dismissed it (that's how I was able to get the screenshot).